# Filtering BindingSource Before Displaying in DataGridView

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have several Windows Forms with DataGridViews. The DataSource for each is bound to a Binding Source, for example 'vendorsBindingSource'. I'd like to filter the data from the Vendors table and show only a few selected rows but I'm not clear how to do that with the designer. I'm running Visual Studio C# Express 2008 and SQL Management Studio 2008 R2, both on an XP machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *Filter* of the *BindingSource*.

Something like this:

```
vendorsBindingSource.Filter = "VendorName Like '%John%'";   // Change the VendorName to the name of the column you want to filter
```

The string you pass to the *vendorsBindingSource.Filter* is basically the same as the one you would pass to an SQL query on a WHERE clause.  Just it has some limitations.

I hope this helps.

Pablo